# How to read .etl files in UWP app

Tags: uwp, etw

I am experimenting with using Windows.Foundation.Diagnostics (File)LoggingSession for tracing and crash logging in an UWP app. I want to allow the user to examine the content of the .etl files before sending them as email attachments. And it would be nice for myself not having to use the cumbersome Windows Performance Analyzer tool.

Is there a possibility to extract the etl events in human readable form in UWP apps, or a etl viewer app?

Comment: you can parse the ETL with this Library: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent

Comment: This lib seems to be incompatible with UWP.

Comment: ok, ask the creator if he can make the library compatible. Comment here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2014/03/15/walk-through-getting-started-with-etw-traceevent-nuget-samples-package.aspx and wait for the reply

Comment: I have just asked to nuget package owner for a UWP compatible version.

Comment: @PeterMeinl  Were you able to find a solution for this ? If yes, Please share with all of us. Thanks!